# How can I use the eOS terminal notification in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, notification, elementary

elementaryOS has the following feature to notify the user of a finished terminal process.

Is it possible to use this feature in Ubuntu?

[image]

**Figure 1: Example of eOS terminal notification**

Comment: I guess it should not be hard. You can use something like `sudo apt-get update && notify-send Task "sudo apt-get update"` and adapt it to your needings.

Comment: Dear @dadexix86, thank you for this "manual" solution. Below answers, however, provide a more automated way which I prefer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want most probably already is available via your `~/.bashrc` courtesy [this](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2010/07/dear-command-line-please-ping-me-when.html) and [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/616028):

*Note: this assumes you have `libnotify-bin` installed. If it isn't, just run `sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin` to get it.*

Check that your `~/.bashrc` has lines like this:

```
# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "Task finished" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
```

Note that "Task finished" isn't present in the original code.

So, in your specific example, you'll run

```
sudo apt-get update; alert
```

If you want the notification to remain on-screen a little longer, use `-t 3000` (in milliseconds). Or, if you want the notification to display until you dismiss it, use `--urgency=critical`.

Here's what I see:

[image: OSD alert]

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/749202/modify-the-alert-alias-in-bashrc for more.

Comment: Great solution! And it is even [supported by default](http://i.imgur.com/zdmHy7I.png) in Ubuntu by now.

Comment: No, I am not. What makes you think that? :)

Comment: The eternal life on the internet. :) Indeed I used dmenu for a while but ultimately stuck with default Ubuntu and use it because it just works. Have fun though!

Answer (score 3):

[undistract-me](https://github.com/jml/undistract-me) provides notifications for terminal commands that take longer than 10 seconds to complete.

1. `sudo apt install undistract-me`
2. `echo 'source /etc/profile.d/undistract-me.sh' >> ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

You can set `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to trigger a `notify-send` command upon a command's completion in `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
PROMPT_COMMAND='notify-send --icon=/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/256x256/apps/utilities-terminal.png "Task finished" "$(history | sed -n "\$s/^  [0-9]\+  //p")"'
```

[image]

The caveat is this can become pretty annoying soon, because it will send a notification each time a command is run.